# Minifying a scss.liquid file

Tags: sass, shopify, minify, web-frontend, shopify-app

Shahzaib here, coming to you for a bit of help !

I'm still new in the Shopify and liquid stuff but i'm getting there.

I'm cutrently trying to minify a scss.liquid file on Shopify, usually when I try to do that with a css file, I use an online minifier, exept that, apprently the scss.liquid format is not properly handled. Every time I try to minify it, my site crash ?

Do you guys have something to recommand regarding minifying a scss.liquid file ?

thanks in advance,

regards, Shahzaib.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting up a gulp task to do this. This will help simplify your SCSS files into individual files for whatever they style. Also, you won't be edited your theme's default theme.scss.liquid file, so it is easier to overwrite default styles, and you know exactly which styling is yours vs the theme's.

To setup a gulp task, you will need to install node.js and gulp. I recommend using npm for this. Here is a good introduction tutorial to this which you'll need to adapt a bit to work with your Shopify file structure. For example, I recommend adding a src directory for your custom .scss files, and compiling them into one single file in the assets directory, instead of working directly in the theme.scss.liquid file.

https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/

Once you have completed those instructions, make sure to add node_modules to your .gitignore file before committing.

Next, setup your project to use themekit. https://shopify.github.io/themekit/ , and have your gulp task run on save of the file. This will compiling your src files into a single file in the assets directory which will then be uploaded to your store by themekit.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd second than10's answer, and add that if minification of static assets is going to be part of your theme development workflow, use gulp.js running locally with something like gulp-shopify-upload watching your changes and pushing them up to your store:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shopify-upload

See basic usage in particular.